# A fatal error when I execute two java application using jnativehook

Tags: java

I have made a java application. It counts mouse clicks and key presses with jnativehook. When I launch the application (jar file) and it starts counting events, I launch a second application in IDE. When that starts counting events, my first app crashes, with the following error message:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000002196, pid=6756, tid=140255629047552
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000002196
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/beknazar/Documents/newjar/tracker-1.0-SNAPSHOT/hs_err_pid6756.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Please, help me find out what is wrong here.

Comment: Looks like a JVM bug. Try with a Java 6 RE or with Oracle's Java 7 RE.

Comment: no, it's other problem. if I copy source code into my project, then it's all ok, but i have maven project, so i don't want to copy sources

Answer (score 0):

It should be resolved in 1.1.4 and 1.2.  IIRC, it was a result of the automagic unpacker trying to overwrite the native library that was already being used by the other instance.